# How can I get just one semicolon with sublime text?

Tags: regex, notepad++, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

I have a file like this

```
a;b;c;d;e;;f;;;
a;b;c;d;e;;f;
a;b;c;d;e;;f;;
a;b;c;d;e;;f;;;;
```

And what I want is to get only one semicolon at the end of each line like this :

```
a;b;c;d;e;;f;
a;b;c;d;e;;f;
a;b;c;d;e;;f;
a;b;c;d;e;;f;
```

I don't know if a regex could be work for this task ?
Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: You could match 1+ semicolons at the end of the string `;+$` and replace with a single semicolon `;`

Answer (score 0):

```
;(;)+$
```

replace with $1

https://regex101.com/r/t90CSc/3

Keep first ; at end, get rid of rest.

Answer (score 0):

- Find what: `;+$`
- Replace with: `;`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: This is using Notepad++, not Sublime Text.

Comment: @user89: So what? Doesn't this question taged `Notepad++`?

Comment: ah ok, I missed that.